# Description of complex conjugate $\operatorname{Spin}^c$ structure without cocycles

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

The following uses exclusively cocycle descriptions for spin and spinc structures which I would like to *avoid*. See for example Nicolaescu "Notes on Seiberg-Witten invariants", pages 40-41 for their use in spin geometry. I know how to define spinc structures via principal bundles which I consider more concise.

Let $M$ be an oriented smooth $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. Let $\rho:\operatorname{Spin}(n)\to \operatorname{Aut}(\Delta_n)$ be the complex spinor representation and  $\rho^\mathrm{c}:\operatorname{Spin^c}(n)\to \operatorname{Aut}(\Delta_n)$ be the "spinc version" of the complex spinor representation.

The definition of a spinc structure needs a $\operatorname{SO}(n)$-principal bundle or equivalently a Riemannian metric. We can describe it via cocycles for an open cover by charts $\mathfrak{U}=(U_i)_{i\in I}$. Denote $U_{ij}:=U_i\cap U_j$.

The manifold $M$ is said to possess a *spinc structure* if there exist smooth maps $g^\mathrm{c}_{ij}:U_{ij}\to \operatorname{Spin^c}(n)$, satisfying the cocycle condition and such that
$\rho^{\mathrm{c}}(g^\mathrm{c}_{ij})=g_{ij}$.

Because of $\operatorname{Spin^c}(n)=\operatorname{Spin}(n)\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}S^1$ this existence is equivalent to the existence of cocycles

$h_{ij}:U_{ij}\to\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ and $z_{ij}:U_{ij}\to S^1$

such that $\rho(h_{ij})=g_{ij}$ and $(h_{ij}h_{jk}h_{ki},z_{ij}z_{jk}z_{ki})\in\{(-1,-1),(1,1) \}$.

Given a spin structure $\mathfrak{s}$ described by cocycles $(h_{ij},z_{ij})$, the spinc structure $-\mathfrak{s}$,  also written $\bar{\mathfrak{s}}$, is given by the cocycles $(h_{ij},\bar{z}_{ij})$.

So how can I formulate this definition in terms of spinc structures as spinc principal bundles?

Comment: There is a natural map spin^c(n) -> SO(n). A spin^c structure is a principal spin^c bundle such that, when you use the above homomorphism to change the structure group, you get back TM. Exactly analogous to the definition of spin structure. BTW: if you care about opinions on where to learn SW-theory, I'm glad to share mine if you email me.

Comment: Thanks. The question was not to reformulate a definition of spin^c structures in general, but a definition of this conjugate or "$-$"-spin^c structure. Would it be the same spin^c bundle, but with opposite action on the second factor of $\mathrm{spin^c}=\mathrm{SO}(n)\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2} S^1$?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I wouldn't say it's the "same" bundle. It's the bundle you get under the homomorphism spin^c -> spin^c that's reflection on the S^1 factor. This is usually not isomorphic to the original spin^c structure!

Comment: Thanks. I meant rather "original" instead of "same", and then the described change. I thought that the bundle is as you just described, but I did not check it expicitely yet. It seems everyone prefers to use the cocycles to describe this conjugate spin^c structure, but I don`t really see the point - it adds a lot of indices etc.